# drupal content adding is slow

Tags: performance, drupal, web

drupal site is slow when adding content. It freezes. I'm new to drupal and I was not aware how to debug it. I'm using the devel module.can someone please suggest the possible reasons for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Do you have any cache module enabled besides core caching functionality ? Modules like Boost can slow down your site as hell if you configure it wrong... Also, don't forget to tag your question with Drupal version.

Answer (score 0):

Does your php memory run out? If you have too many modules installed, this can happen. You can fix this by changing the phpmem variable in your server config file. A typical indication for this is the white screen.

You can also check your server apache and sql logs and see if they give you any clues.

Comment: thanks you very much for the reply. What I could find is sess_write is talking lot of time for every page. will this  be a possible reason for that?

Comment: hi everyone,

I would like to disable the sess_write or speed up.that is causing lot of problem for the site. Can anyone guide me in the process. I'm new to drupal,so kindly help me in this.thanks in advance